# Sticky footer in vuejs application

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I'm struggling with making a sticky footer work in my vuejs application.

vuejs and other framework like it, require that a root element be present in the template.

But this is making it difficult to use Flex to add a sticky footer.

without the root element:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sticky Footer with Flexbox</h1>
  <p>
    <button id="add">Add Content</button>
  </p>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer
</footer>
```

everything works for, but with the root element, it doesn't.

```
<div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Sticky Footer with Flexbox</h1>
    <p>
      <button id="add">Add Content</button>
    </p>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Since removing the root element is not an option, please how can I update the css to work with the root element?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/capiono/Low3fbs1/2/)

Comment: Simply change the `body` rule to `body > div {...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set an `id` to the outer `div` (e.g `id="app"`) and use the css-rules that you defined for `body`:

```
<div id="app">
  ...
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Low3fbs1/4/

Comment: works awesome!!